# Wondering the big O notation value of my script?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

It's been a little while since I estimated the big O notation on something and I can't seem to get a handle on this one. Basically my script runs through a list of points in the USA with latitude/longitude and finds a set that covers the country if those points are the center of circles with 100 mile radius. So like this:

- Start looping through the list, index i = 0.
- Find the distance between the ith point in the list and all points that follow it in the list.
- Remove any points that are within 100 miles
- Re-index the array
- Increase the index by one
- If i = list length, end, else, loop

Comment: We'd need to see your actual code in order to determine the actual Big-O.

Comment: I'm not clear on your algorithm.  If your goal is to find **a** set of points, why are you removing any?  Are you actually looking for a **minimum** set of points that covers the country?

Comment: The question has already been answered, but I thought it is worth noting that worst case for this algorithm is when your points are sorted (say east-west).

Comment: So, what's **your** estimate of your program's complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You algorithm is `O(N^2)`, where `n`. If I understand your description correctly, it goes something like this:

```
for point A in array:
  for point B in array:
      d = dist(A,B)
      //optionally remove from list
```

In the worst case, every pair of points is more than 100 miles apart, so you end up checking the distance between each pair, hence `O(N^2)`.

Note you are doing at most `n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1 = (n(n+1))/2` distance calculations, which  is still `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime of your algorithm is `O(n^2)`, as at the worst case you iterate through the array and check each point against all the following points in the array, thus `n(n-1)/2` comparisons, which is `O(n^2)`

I must tell you though that I don't think this algorithm provides the right solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `n` is the number of points you have as input.

> Start looping through the list, index i = 0.
>
> ...
>
> If i = list length, end, else, loop

So that's `n` iterations.

> Find the distance between the ith point in the list and all points that follow it in the list.

That's `n` operations per iteration. If it were just these two it ends up being `n^2/2` (every point with every other point, except order doesn't matter so you do half the comparisons).

> Remove any points that are within 100 miles
>
> Re-index the array

From what it sounds like, you're nulling out those elements that are within 100 miles, then shifting the array. Both of which are `O(n)` operations, which ends up being `O(n^2)` since you have an `O(n)` operation repeated `n` times.

So you end up having `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I object to you saying `O(n^2/2 + n^2)` is "more specific" than `O(n^2)`. They're the same. The one just has a bunch of trivial data. If you wish to specify constant factors, consider [tilde (~) notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).

Comment: @Dukeling: it is more specific, because although the order is the same, it gives you more information. An algorithm that is `O(14n)` is still 7 times slower than an algorithm that is `O(2n)`, even though it doesn't matter for large `n`. But for small `n` it might. Likewise if one algorithm is `O(43009n^2)` and the other is `O(n^3)`, you might want to use the `O(n^3)` one if your `n` is small enough, but if you see just `O(n^2)` vs `O(n^3)` you don't have as much info to make that decision.

Comment: But you can also say an algorithm that runs 14 times for each element is `O(2n)`. (And `O(n^2)` for that matter, though here you can say `O(n)` is "more specific".) By definition, constant factors and asymptotically smaller terms mean nothing in big-O notation. Attributing some meaning to them is flawed.

Comment: @Dukeling: hmm yes, i think you're right. as you say a different notation should be used to specify that.